# How to archive different pages that don't have a different URL?

Tags: bookmarks, website

I was trying to archive "[Academia Guatemalteca de la Lengua. Breve historia](http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua)" and "[Academia Guatemalteca de la Lengua. Los académicos](http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua)", but I discovered that both pages have the same URL; if I archive the URL and try to click "Los académicos" it will try to load it as a different web page entirely, so I need to archive those two links separately. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- right-click on **Los académicos** button
- select **Open link in new tab**
- copy your URL (notice **?qt-tab=2#qt-tab**)

**http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua?qt-tab=0#qt-tab
http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua?qt-tab=1#qt-tab
http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua?qt-tab=2#qt-tab
http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua?qt-tab=3#qt-tab**

Answer (score 0):

Los academicos is http://www.asale.org/academias/academia-guatemalteca-de-la-lengua?qt-tab=2#qt-tab -- it's a not-so-well-designed ajax-y website and I was able to copy the url for the Los academicos box.